# failure: repodata/repomd.xml from rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms: [Errno 256] No more HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

➜  production yum update
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                           | 7.5 kB  00:00:00
https://mirrors.bestthaihost.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's Certificate has expired."
Trying other mirror.
It was impossible to connect to the Red Hat servers.
This could mean a connectivity issue in your environment, such as the requirement to configure a proxy,
or a transparent proxy that tampers with TLS security, or an incorrect system clock.
Please collect information about the specific failure that occurs in your environment,
using the instructions in: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1527033 and open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

epel                                                                                                           | 4.7 kB  00:00:00
nginx                                                                                                          | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
remi-safe                                                                                                      | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
https://rhui3.ap-south-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/content/content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7Server/x86_64/rh-common/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/69319

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

One of the configured repositories failed (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - RH Common from RHUI (RPMs)),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://rhui3.ap-south-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/content/content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7Server/x86_64/rh-common/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

```
#subscription-manager repos --disable=*;
        
#subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-rpms > --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms > --enable=rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms;yum clean all
        
#yum update -y
```